# How do I set ng-bind as value returned from angular http?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, http

I want the value returned from my http in angularjs to be set as result in my variable ng-bind. SO that, when I type in text, the result should be the value returned from the HTTP request.

Here is my code:

This is my AngularJS part which will have the text box for writing. The output should be the value returned from the next http part.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model={{myWelcome}}></p>
<p ng-bind={{myWelcome}}></p>
</div>
```

And this is the http part. The response should be binded in ng-bind. How do I do that?

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://146.148.85.67/processWordJSON?inString=namasthe&lang=hindi")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain that `when I type in text, the result should be the value returned from the HTTP request` ?

Comment: @BillP Actually it's like, I type something & the http will send that word as variable and will return the translated value. The ng-bind should contain that translated value and should show that value outside the text box as result. To be more clear, the second part of my code i.e **script** contains http and it has **inString** as variable. My text from textbox should be passed as this inString variable. And the return value from this http should be passed to myWelcome, which goes in ng-bind in first part of code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, 
You want to get the user input with a textbox and display the translation (which you get via api) in the `<p>` below

**You are using the same model for the text box and `<p>`**

You would need something like this:

You can wrap your http.get call in a method:

```
$scope.GetTranslation = function(){

return  $http.get("http://146.148.85.67/processWordJSON?inString=namasthe&lang=hindi")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
}
```

and in your html:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-change="GetTranslation()" ng-model={{inString}}></p>
<p ng-model={{myWelcome}}></p>
</div>
```

And use your inString variable to make the api call